# How to get a DLL to programmatically obtaint it's version?

Tags: vb.net, dll, version

VB.NET, Framework 3.5. 
Working on a DLL, the DLL needs to programmatically determine it's own version

Can seem to use the Application Class

My.Application.Info.Version.Major etc. shows info from the client app calling the DLL

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GetExecutingAssembly`, as [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) states:

> Gets the assembly that contains the code that is currently executing

so you can write:

```
Dim version = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version
```